# Python if valuea is equal and if valueb is not equal

Tags: python, xbmc

i made  little script to work with xbmc and i'm not able to get it work. Here the code:

```
import xbmcgui
import xbmc

while (not xbmc.abortRequested):

    win = (xbmcgui.getCurrentWindowId())
    menu = 0

    if win == 10000 and menu != 10000:
        print ("Home menu")
        menu = 10000
```

All i want is that when home menu is there, write to log (but only once) for now it always write in the log when on menu

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your indentation is not currently valid after the `while` or the `if`.

Comment: Please edit your question to ident the code correctly, in the case of Python, it's essential to understand where each block starts and ends.

Comment: I can see why you must be getting errors.

Comment: You means the space, in the code there some space for the indentation, but when i copy pass the code, space have been earase. If i understand what you mean, sorry i'm a newbie in python

Comment: Accept the answer. You have lots of open questions.

Answer (score 5):

Set `menu = 0` *outside* of your `while` loop; you are resetting it to 0 each time otherwise:

```
menu = 0

while (not xbmc.abortRequested):
    win = (xbmcgui.getCurrentWindowId())

    if win == 10000 and menu != 10000:
        print ("Home menu")
        menu = 10000
```